My C++ code is not taking any input, only cin is causing the trouble not cout. Even the online compilers are showing timeout error
The cpp code that I wrote while solving an online solution, was running indefinitely, even though it was not supposed to. So I pinpointed the line that was causing the problem- it was the cin line.
I don't know what is happening here, even the online compiler is showing timeout error in the code. This all started when I was practicing questions on codeforces and when I run it, it was running indefinitely.
The original code screenshot->
the code that I typed on my machine, which was running indefinitely
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    cout << "hello world, the value of t is = " << t << endl;

    return 0;
}

The code in question->
the hello world code, in an online compiler showing timeout error
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    cout << "hello world, the value of t is = " << t << endl;

    return 0;
}

What can I try next?

There is nothing in your code that would cause a timeout or make it run indefinitely. Although an online system might complain if you do not type in a value within some specific time interval.

It's not "running indefinitely" - it's waiting for you to actually type something. What else did you expect cin >> t to do?

I suggest you go to https://www.learncpp.com and work through the tutorial.
